# Regex: get all numeric and special characters starting with specific letters, stop when space occurs after number

Tags: python, regex

I have this text example:

> LALL - 4302 is broken, while LALL-4301 and LALL 3305 are being fixed.

I want to capture:

```
LALL - 4302, LALL-4301, LALL 3305
```

I see the pattern as it starts with "*LALL*" and captures the following numbers, special characters, and spaces, then stops once the number is followed by space.

How can I do it using RegEx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `re.findall`:

```
inp = "LALL - 4302 is broken, while LALL-4301 and LALL 3305 are being fixed."
matches = re.findall(r'\bLALL\s*-?\s*\S+', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['LALL - 4302', 'LALL-4301', 'LALL 3305']
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to make more restrictions in which what follows "LALL" will always be either number, space, or "-"? Because I don't want to capture "LALL ABC" (for example)

Comment: I suggest opening a new question.