# Regex: get numeric, space, or "-" characters after specific string

Tags: python, regex

This question is related to:
[Regex: get all numeric and special characters starting with specific letters, stop when space occurs after number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200388/regex-get-all-numeric-and-special-characters-starting-with-specific-letters-st/60200427?noredirect=1#comment106484347_60200427)

but I have a rule that LALL must be followed by either number, space, or "-".
How can I do that using regex?

Thanks!

Comment: You could change the `\S+` to `\d+`?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60218894/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
\bLALL\s*[-\s\d]\s*\d+
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/7zqpWl/1)**

## Explanation:

To capture any space, digit or hyphen (`\s`, `\d` or `-`), you can use `[-\s\d]`, which may have zero or more spaces on either side.